# How to generate a thumbnail image after adding a video inside an input type=“file” in a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic framework app (angular) that will upload videos to a back-end service. I would like to show a thumbnail of the video selected ( or just taken by the mobile device ) on the form before user submits. I have found many useful examples to do this for images, but not videos. Any advice?